# How to show a text based on the current url?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using vue-router, and I'm trying to keep a title that identifies the section for example:

In my main navigation I want to show the text of the current section (not the active class, just a simple text with the section).

Pattern of urls:

Root / section / subsectionA => show Section in navigation

Root / sectionX / subectionA => Display SectionX in navigation

I do not know if I understood

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can access any of your route `params` by define a **slug**. so you route will be something like this:

```
router.map({
    '/:slug/subsectionA': {
        component: your_component,
        name: 'section'
    },
})
```

then you can access the `:slug` dynamic slot in your view like this:

```
this.$route.params.slug
```